# SqlDataReader does not return all records

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am experiencing a problem with ADO.NET SqlDataReader. When I run underlying stored procedure directly in SSMS - it returns 1.7 million of records. When I run a related VB.NET code that fills an ADO.NET DataTable - I also get 1.7 million of records.

But when I run a loop to fill a Generic list like this

```
While i_oDataReader.Read
   m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))
End While
```

It returns a lot less records and that number can vary. At the end of the loop if I check `m_aFullIDList.Count` it ca be 100000 or 500000 etc. Any idea why and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an exception, maybe a [timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1719463/284240)?

Comment: No, the loops runs thru without any errors, just the count at the end is wrong. It's sounds silly but it's almost as if SQL Server cannot catch up with DataReader and the loop is finished before full result is returned.

Comment: But actually you reference pointed me to the right direction. Adding "CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess" while creating the DataReader fixed the issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to reference pointed by @Tim Schemlter I found the option "CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess" for DataReader creation. That fixed the issue. E.g. instead of

```
drReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

use

```
drReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
```

and it works correctly.

Comment: No, not a blob, plain Int, but a whole lot of those.

Comment: And a funny thing - it takes about 14 seconds to execute query directly in SSMS, but only about a second to execute a loop above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the GetInt64() method instead?  I realize that with *only* 1.7 million records, the GetInt32() method should be large enough; I was more just curious.

Also, if you think that SQL cannot keep up with the DataReader, have you tried adding a wait in the loop to allow it to catch up?