# SqlDataReader does not read all records

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqldatareader, datareader

I have a very weird problem in the most simple piece of VB.NET code:

```
Public Sub ReadIDs(i_oDataReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader)

    m_aFullIDList = New Generic.List(Of Integer)

    While i_oDataReader.Read
        If i_oDataReader.IsDBNull(0) = False Then
            m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))
        End If
    End While

    m_iTotalNumberOfRecords = m_aFullIDList.Count

End Sub
```

Basically the procedure accepts a DataReader as a parameter, loops thru all the records in the reader, adding them to a Generic list of integer.

When SQL Stored Procedure that is behind the reader returns relatively small amount of records (below 100K) reader reads all the records and the final count matches the resultset. But when the number of records is over 1 million - results become unpredictable.

E.g. When I know that SP rerturns 1.5M of records - final count of records in Generic list could be 200K, 500K etc.

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of application, ASP.NET or other multi-threading type?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. ASP.NET as a matter of fact.

Comment: Is it reproducable on debugging or only in production? Is anything static(shared) like the connection? Do you get an exception?

Comment: First thing to do is to run the code in isolation - perhaps cut a paste to a test program. Check if it succeeds. If it does then the error is likely be some interaction with  another part of the program. If it's the same then you need to go deeper and isolate the the point (number of rows) at which it causes an error. Then try finding out which part of the infrastructure is broken - by replacing parts eg.g reader with dataset, the db engine? etc etc.. Also put try catches in to see if exceptions are raised to help you.

Comment: Behaves the same way in isolated code. I noticed if I use simple `i_oDataReader(0)` instead of `i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0)` I get correct count more often, but every now and then reader throws a NullReferenceException for some reason.

Comment: According to the code you posted, it only adds the record to the list if the first column of the result set is not null.  Are you sure that the first column of the result set for all records returned has a value?

Comment: Yes, it's an integer Identity field. That check is there just as a precaution and not really needed there. If I remove it - behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to use the [`ExecuteReader` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) that allows you to specify a `CommandBehavior`, and pass `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` as recommended in this MSDN topic:

[Retrieving Large Data (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49.aspx).

Comment: Already using

ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection + CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

doesn't seem to help. About breaking into chunks - how would I do this? I do not control the SP

Comment: I've only just seen that you're the one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12464309/284240 So it dos _not work correctly_.

Comment: Sorry about duplicate, decided to get a fresh view. That was a strange thing - it *seemed* to work for a while, and then had no more effect. Have no idea why.