# How to get C# ExecuteReader to throw exception instead of hang

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0

I have an application open which has called performed a SELECT using "FOR UPDATE" - locking the row.

When a second application tries to access the same row the application hangs (untill it times out) on:

```
// Simplified code
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection, transaction);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); // HANGS
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it says under SqlException:

> An exception occurred while executing the command against a locked row

This is what I would like - to get an exception immediately.
I tried to change the command timeout, but this just gives a TimeoutException and nothing explaining that the accurate reason.

Comment: You are referencing MSDN documentation which pertains to `SqlCommand.ExcecuteReader()`. In your code you are using `MySqlCommand.ExcecuteReader()` which as far as I know is not part of the .NET Framework. What does the specific documentation of the developer of class `MySqlCommand` say?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using try and catch?

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
try

{


connection.Open();

var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection, transaction);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
}
catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Yes - sorry for simplified code. Everything is in try-catch. Problem is that program hangs on the command.ExecuteReader line untill it times out. Then a timeout exception is thrown

Comment: Check this.Hope it'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719305/timeout-exception-causes-sqldatareader-to-close

Comment: Nope, no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

SqlExceptionThe default timeout period for SQL connection is something like 15 or 30 seconds. When your code attempts to read the data it waits for an answer or timeout. One way of doing this (I'm not sure how practical it is though - only a beginner at SQL) is reducing the timeout period and attempting to reconnect, while refreshing the program:

```
connection.ConnectionTimeout = 1; //timeout in seconds
//initialize command, connection etc
bool commited;
while(!commited){
   try{
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
      commited = true;
   }catch(SqlException e) {
      commited = false;
   }
   //code to force program update.
}
```

And if you really want the "locked row" message, you can do it after 15 (or whatever amount you choose) of 1 second timeouts.

Comment: This is a very general solution which will only tell you whether a timeout ocurred - it will throw a timeout exception and not a more specific SQL related one.

Comment: My idea is to reduce time out period and to attempt several connections between which the program could update, rather than waiting for 15 or 30 seconds.
You could also just reduce the timeout period and then catch an exception. Without asynchronous connection or multi-threading the program will hand either way, because until timeout period passes it WILL keep waiting for an answer, only question is how long will it be frozen. Sadly, I can't help much beyond this.